# Error installing Windows 8 RTM, probably nx/PAE support

Tags: windows-8, nx, pae

I'm having trouble installing Windows 8 RTM. When the install starts it shows me an `error 0x0000005D`, which I found on the internet and is about the nx/PAE feature. I have an Intel Celeron 2.8GHz and using the `Coreinfo.exe` I found that it supports nx and PAE. However I can't find a way to enable them in the BIOS. I have a Gigabyte motherboard GA-8S648FX updated with the latest BIOS version and there is no choise of enabling these features. Is there a way to do so?

I alos found that if I run the `sources\setup.exe` file, the install doesn't look for nx/PAE support and then if it is supported by the CPU it enables it. I tried this but I still got the same error. Is there any other way to enabe it, or is there any other hardware problem that cancels the install? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I set the XD bit to 'enabled' in the BIOS setup and it worked. Unlike the posts on the internet, the XD bit is displayed either in the BIOS tab or ADVANCED tab.

Steps:
Boot your PC into setup BIOS mode by pressing the 'Delete' key continuously during boot.

When in BIOS settings, search for the XD flag either in BIOS or ADVANCED tab. If you can find it, then search it in all other tabs.This depends pn PC manufacturer and can be located in any other tab.

Set the XD flag to 'Enabled' and you are done.

Boot the PC and you are ready to install Windows 8.

Let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as it seems I cannot install windows cause i found in the Intel site that my CPU doesn't support NX :/
than you for your time however :)